# How to generate tables in parallel with tpc-ds benchmark?

Tags: apache-spark, tpc

How do I run tpc-ds data generation (`dsdgen`) and then run queries on these data (`dsqgen`) in a parallel distributed mode. I am using Spark on yarn configuration (`spark.master yarn`) and storing data on a burst buffer storage system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check my current exploration @ https://github.com/dhiraa/spark-tpcds. t
There is application under t which can be used to generate data in parallel.

Or you could check out my reference @ https://github.com/maropu/spark-tpcds-datagen

In both the cases don't forget to use the option "--partition-tables" to make use of the parallel generation.